# Convert binary file to excel file

Tags: excel, converters, bin

I have an external application which gives me bin file. The users of this application store the files as .xls and the application transforms them to .bin and I have just access to .bin.
Is there any tool or method that allows me to convert this .bin to the original .xls

Comment: That is going to depend on what you mean by *'transforms them to .bin'*. Have you tried renaming them to see if no real conversion takes place?

Comment: Yes I renamed them to .xls but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Well, then it stands to reason that nothing can be done to undo it without knowing what was done in the first place.